# I cannot push code to ionic master

Tags: git, macos, ionic-framework, terminal

I'm having an issue with the new ionic pro app deployment and testing through GIT. I've gone through process of manually linking old ionic cloud project to the new ionic pro system and then when I finally run the command to push to ionic master:

```
git push ionic master
```

It asks me for the ionic passphrase key...

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/Coolwebs/.ssh/ionic/113316':
```

I've gone looking for the passphrase in my macosx keychain (searching for 'SSH'), but all I can find is an entry for GitHub and I'm sure that isn't the right entry (even though I already tried using the password).

I even created a new app according to instructions on https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/migration/index.html and then I still get the same request for a passphrase for the very same key.

I think this refers to the original SSH that I setup when I first installed GIT - but I have no idea what that is. Totally pulling my hair out over this.

Do I need to uninstall GIT and reinstall it all over again?

Comment: After setting up a new ionic app on a different mac machine, I realised that my ionic ssh install is the problem. I removed/deleted the .config and also the ionic ssh keys from my computer and then ran 'ionic ssh generate' again. No more issues.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to reinstall GIT.

To quote ionic docs:

> The Ionic CLI automatically detects and adds your public key (or creates new ones) to your Ionic Pro account as part of the link and start commands. If you have additional public keys you’d like to link to Ionic Pro, create them manually using ssh-keygen, log into your Ionic Pro account, and add the keys manually under “SSH Keys”.

Comment: I solved the issue but I can't exactly remember what I did. I think I pretty much scrubbed everything in ionic pro and in my local. Then created a brand new ionic project, linked it to ionic pro and my github. Then manually brought across all my files (from old ionic 1 app) into it.